# SharePoint 2010 web part on 2013 SharePoint environment

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2012

Can I create a 2010 visual web part on SharePoint 2013 environment using visual studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you copy SP 2010 assemblies and then refer those as part of developing the webpart.

Make sure your target framework is v3.5.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, with no problem at all.
I usually work that way with no problem, just move the wsp and deploy it.
The deploy will stay in the folder 14, not in the 15, for that "problem" you could use the following command:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity InterviewTestWebpart.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15}
```

Good Luck

Comment: How you will refer the assemblies? I have a 2013 setup and I haven't seen 2010 SharePoint assemblies in any place.

Comment: What is a reference? A reference is just an indicator, in the project, that you will use that class, but when you package the solution, there is no reference. a wsp is a cab file, please change the extension and open it, and tell me where there is a reference?

When you realice a reference in the project is just to use it, but when you build the solution, the solution will go to take the dll's that the system have

Comment: sorry i didnt try to offend you. I placed your name before my question but for some reason it didnt came through. By reference I meant the object model code which is specific to 2013. In 2013 SharePoint dll has more features compared to 2010, so how it works. As you said if the objects that are being used is compatible with 2010 then only it will work.

Comment: There ir no problem, I accidentally pressed the enter, there is my full answer

Comment: Its giving me this error.. SharePoint not installed , the required version of SharePoint foundation 2010 is not installed on this system. To develop SharePoint solutions or browse SharePoint connections in server explorer , SharePoint must be installed on the local system. Make sure that the local server referenced by the SharePoint project exists

Comment: Hi @Avinash to develop for sharepoint 2010 or 2013 you need to have an environment with SharePoint and develop on it. You can't develop remotely.
If you need help with a local environment, just ask :)